# xslt: how to normalize numerical element

Tags: xslt

I would like to add an element to existing XML file with normalized value of existing element in the XML. 
Any help would be extremely appreciated.

regards

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>10</b>
        <c>12</c>
        <d>9</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>8</b>
        <c>50</c>
        <d>12</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>6</b>
        <c>55</c>
        <d>56</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>yes</a>
        <b>23</b>
        <c>32</c>
        <d>34</d>
    </Results>
</top>
```

In the sample input xml above, I would like to add "b_nom" elements to each of the results where the value is (b)/(minimum of 'b' grouped with a). The expected output is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>10</b>
        <b_nom>1.66</b_nom>
        <c>12</c>
        <d>9</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>8</b>
        <b_nom>1.33</b_nom>
        <c>50</c>
        <d>12</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>6</b>
        <b_nom>1</b_nom>
        <c>55</c>
        <d>56</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>yes</a>
        <b>23</b>
        <b_nom>1</b_nom>
        <c>32</c>
        <d>34</d>
    </Results>
</top>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'minimum of b grouped with a'?

Comment: Can you give the formula that you're using to calculate `b_nom`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="Results" use="a"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:variable name="min">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', ../a)">
      <xsl:sort select="b" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="b"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <b_nom>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(. div $min, '0.##')"/>
  </b_nom>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a changed version of the stylesheet that takes a couple of values identifying a group into account:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:data="http:://example.com/data"
  exclude-result-prefixes="data">

<data:data xmlns="">
  <group>
    <key>no</key>
    <values>
      <value>no</value>
      <value>n</value>
      <value>0</value>
    </values>
  </group>
  <group>
    <key>yes</key>
    <values>
      <value>yes</value>
      <value>y</value>
      <value>1</value>
    </values>
  </group>
</data:data>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="main-input" select="/"/>

<xsl:variable name="groups" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/data:data/group"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="min">
    <xsl:for-each select="$main-input//Results[a = $groups/values[value = $this/../a]/value]">
      <xsl:sort select="b" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="b"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <b_nom>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(. div $min, '0.##')"/>
  </b_nom>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<top>
    <Results>
        <a>no</a>
        <b>10</b>
        <c>12</c>
        <d>9</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>n</a>
        <b>8</b>
        <c>50</c>
        <d>12</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>0</a>
        <b>6</b>
        <c>55</c>
        <d>56</d>
    </Results>
    <Results>
        <a>yes</a>
        <b>23</b>
        <c>32</c>
        <d>34</d>
    </Results>
</top>
```

into the output

```
<top>
   <Results>
      <a>no</a>
      <b>10</b>
      <b_nom>1.67</b_nom>
      <c>12</c>
      <d>9</d>
   </Results>
   <Results>
      <a>n</a>
      <b>8</b>
      <b_nom>1.33</b_nom>
      <c>50</c>
      <d>12</d>
   </Results>
   <Results>
      <a>0</a>
      <b>6</b>
      <b_nom>1</b_nom>
      <c>55</c>
      <d>56</d>
   </Results>
   <Results>
      <a>yes</a>
      <b>23</b>
      <b_nom>1</b_nom>
      <c>32</c>
      <d>34</d>
   </Results>
</top>
```

Comment: The Solution works well, Thank you.     To further my understanding, is it possible extend this to have normalized values of 'b' for certain groups of 'a', suppose 'a' could take values of 'no','n','false', 'yes','y','true' and I would like to group them into 1. 'no','n','false' and 2. 'yes','y','true' ?

Comment: @user1495523, I have provided a second code sample that takes the values forming a group into account.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solves a bulk of my problem.

Comment: Martin, Could I please ask you to help me further, I want to normalize a new element which would be an average of two elements. (say c & d in the above example)

Comment: Ask a new question, I am sure someone can help.